# Library to connect node.js to virtuoso graph?

Tags: session, node.js, virtuoso

My first project using two different new technologies would be to implement some session management on node.js, storing the session & user data into a Virtuoso Datastore.

It's exciting, because I'm an old school C# / Java developer used to MySQL / SQL.

Do you Guys know of the right libraries an examples to study, and be able to complete this first auto-challenge?

Comment: Just got aware of this DB, seems incredibly multi-featured, really wish there would be a driver so I can do some performance testing with it!

Comment: Just work with the REST API. I recommend you this library (in coffescript) for starters: https://github.com/aldonline/node-sparql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of node.js library for Virtuoso as you have for MySQL, Postgres and the like. Connections to Virtuoso for querying the Quad Store can be made via HTTP using the Web Server [(VSP)](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/vspquickstart.html) or [SPARQL endpoint](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparql.html#rdfsparqlprotocolendpoint) or using any of the Data Access interface we have drivers/providers for which include, [ODBC, JDBC, ADO.Net, OLEDB](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/accessinterfaces.html) or [RDF Data providers](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfnativestorageproviders.html) Jena, Sesame, Redland and others. Thus does node.js have generic libraries for connection to servers via any of these means ?

Comment: Yes, asyc REST API is the solution. This library, gets it done: https://github.com/aldonline/node-sparql

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/Tomas2D/virtuoso-connector NPM library, just released.

```js
import { DatabaseConnection } from 'virtuoso-connector'

const db = new DatabaseConnection({
  url: 'jdbc:virtuoso://127.0.0.1:1111/CHARSET=UTF-8',
  username: 'dba',
  password: 'dba',
  driverPath: '/usr/local/vos/lib/jdbc-4.2/virtjdbc4_2.jar',
  lazy: false,
  maxQueryTimeout: 360, // optional (in seconds), 0 = unlimited
  poolSize: 2 // max active connections
})

const results = await db.query(`
  SELECT ?s ?p ?o 
  WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }
  LIMIT 10
`)

results.forEach(result => {
  console.info(result.s, result.p, result.o)
})

// Destroy connection
db.destroy()
```

Another approach is to use Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint where you can send HTTP requests.

PS: I am the author.

Comment: Please be sure to read [Stack Overflow's self-promotion policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when referencing your own content.